# openID and CakePHP : myopenID works, yahoo does not

Tags: cakephp, openid

I have set up a basic openID system using cakePHP (http://code.42dh.com/openid/)  on my dev website: http://dev.cyclistsroadmap.com/users/login  (forgive the debug output). It works perfectly for myopenID but does not for yahoo (flickr icon)

It returns with a identity url but insists "OpenID verification failed: No OpenID information found  at https://me.yahoo.com/a/...." and doesn't work at all for google.

The fact that it works for myopenID leads me to believe that I have things set up correctly. Any clues as to why Yahoo is failing depsite the URL coming back?

EDIT: It appears that PHP might not be able to do SSL, is it possible that that is what is causing the Yahoo to fail?

Answer (score 4):

I've been down this exact same path just recently, took me a while to figure out. Have a look in your PHP error log, for me that's `MAMP/logs/php_error.log`. You'll probably find something along these lines:

```
Got no response code when fetching https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud  
CURL error (60): SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
```

This may be a problem in local PHP/OpenSSL installations. The easiest way to fix this is to disable SSL verification in the bundled Yadis ParanoidHTTPFetcher:

```
Index: /app/vendors/Auth/Yadis/ParanoidHTTPFetcher.php
===================================================================
--- a/app/vendors/Auth/Yadis/ParanoidHTTPFetcher.php
+++ b/app/vendors/Auth/Yadis/ParanoidHTTPFetcher.php
@@ -131,7 +131,9 @@
             if (defined('Auth_OpenID_VERIFY_HOST')) {
                 curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
                 curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
+            } else {
+                curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
             }
             curl_exec($c);

             $code = curl_getinfo($c, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
@@ -204,6 +206,8 @@
         if (defined('Auth_OpenID_VERIFY_HOST')) {
             curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
             curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
+        } else {
+            curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
         }

         curl_exec($c);
```

To *enable* SSL host verification on your production system, add something like this in `core.php`:

```
if (!Configure::read('debug')) {
    define('Auth_OpenID_VERIFY_HOST', true);
}
```

Comment: This appears to have worked for Flickr (I think) will continue trying. Thanks for the solution! I wish this were a proper option rather than a hack. I'm on a pretty cheap server so I can easily imagine that the SSL is not really set up for me.